# tan additions formula expressions only representing with tan

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This is expression for $\tan(a+b+y)$

$$\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)+\tan(y)−\tan(a)\tan(b)\tan(y)}{1−
\tan(a)\tan(b)−\tan(a)\tan(y)−\tan(b)\tan(y)}$$

I want to represent this with only $\tan(a)$, $\tan(b)$ and $\tan(y)$.

Clearly,I want to replace $1$ with tan functions of these three variables.

I need this answer because thie is from GelfAndSaul Trigonometry Book questions.Pg-145

Comment: oh thz... I edited

Comment: Wait, what are you asking? You want to express it in terms of $\tan (a), \tan (b)$ and $\tan (c)$? You already have an expression in them though.

Comment: no.... only in terms of tan(a),tan(b) and tan(c)? there is 1.

Comment: Even the $1$? $1 = \tan^0 a$.

Comment: Yep............

Comment: I think you are stuck with the $1$. (What would the answer be if $a$, $b$ and $y$ were all $0$ or very near $0$?). If you [edit] the question to tell us _why_ you need this perhaps we can help. (Don't answer in a comment.) I note that this is the second time you have asked the same question.

Comment: Yes. This is the second time

Comment: And i edited for why i need to know

Comment: I don't think that they mean that even the $1$ shouldn't be there. They just mean that there shouldn't be things like $\tan (a+b)$.

Comment: Stop posting duplicates of your own questions, Plus I already gave you complete solution for it.